# Building CRM Web Resources with React

Tags: reactjs, dynamics-crm

I am new Dynamics CRM. My project includes form submissions and validations. I am planning to build a product using a React with Redux frontend and a service from CRM.

What will be the best practice in CRM on Building CRM Web Resources
Can anyone guide me?

https://github.com/sonomapartners/web-resources-with-react

```
import 'babel-polyfill'; 
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import CaseSummary from './components/CaseSummary.jsx'; 

window.addEventListener('load', function onLoad() { 
  ReactDOM.render( <CaseSummary />, 
  document.getElementById("container") ); 
});
```

Comment: Hey there, dev from sonoma here. React and redux are still totally relevant. However, that repo is super old at this point. I would recommend looking into the PowerApps Component Framework instead of web resources: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-powerapps-component-framework-and-the-powerapps-cli-is-now-available-for-public-preview/

Answer (score 5):

1. **Get context:**

   - Add `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` in the  in the `index.html`: 
     `<script type="text/javascript" src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx">`. [ClientGlobalContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/getglobalcontext-clientglobalcontext.js.aspx) is the offical hook to Dynamics form context.
   - In the React `componentDidMount` life cycle, Add `const context = GetGlobalContext();` to get the context object. 
     if you send data to the WebResource with the [OpenWebResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openwebresource)(webResourceName, windowOptions, data), you can get the data in this way: `JSON.parse(context.getQueryStringParameters().Data);`
2. **Intellisense:** if you are using `TypeScript` use the d.ts (definition) file: `///<reference path=Xrm.V9.d.ts/>`. you can get it [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/xrm/index.d.ts).
3. **Uplaod**: WebRersource can't be `jsx` or `tsx` type. After you compile your project you should only upload the bundled file (bundle.js).
4. **Debug:** If you want to debug your jsx/tsx file, you will need to use fiddler's AutoResponder to use the source map file. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/streamline-javascript-development-fiddler-autoresponder) is an explanation.

Comment: can you do the same for my question 

Comment: @user264675, I did it! 