# Material-ui for PowerApps?

Tags: reactjs, dynamics-crm, material-ui, powerapps

I want to put `material-ui` table app into a PowerApps app, is it possible? if so, how?

I already have the code and the bundle made with webpack, actually I am on the step that I don't know how to add it to Powerapps.

Comment: when you say PowerApps - Canvas Or Model driven?

Comment: Both of them, i will choose whichever could run my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model driven PowerApps will allow you to add external JS libraries, HTML web pages, CSS, etc as Web resources to design a custom UI within Dynamics. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/web-resources)

For example, the [ReactJS is used in Dynamics web resource](https://crm-rocks.com/reactjs-as-dynamics-365-ce-web-resource/) like below using `bundle.js`. Same approach you should try.

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <link href="./static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Step by step instructions in another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56622495/7920473) will give you an idea.

Canvas is a low-code WYSIWYG app builder, so you won't get a lot of support there to do all this custom UI development with third party libraries.

Comment: I finally were able to do it and its working fine, thank you for your help!